# Priority queue implemented with a ConcurrentSkipListMap, unsure how to make consumers block on it

Tags: java, multithreading, priority-queue

I have a priority queue implemented with a ConcurrentSkipListMap, using 16 different priorities.

```
class ConcurrentPriorityQueue {

    ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, Message> queue = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    AtomicLong counter16 = new AtomicLong(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    AtomicLong counter15 = new AtomicLong(Long.MAX_VALUE / 8 * 7);
    AtomicLong counter14 = new AtomicLong(Long.MAX_VALUE / 4 * 3);
    // etc
    AtomicLong counter1 = new AtomicLong(Long.MIN_VALUE / 8 * 7);

    void addPriority16(Message message) {
        queue.put(counter16.getAndDecrement(), message);
    }

    void addPriority15(Message message) {
        queue.put(counter15.getAndDecrement(), message);
    }

    // and so on
}
```

This isn't exactly how the class is organized (e.g. I've got the AtomicLongs in an array), but I figured this code would be clearer.  There's also a DelayQueue to remove old messages or to raise the priority on old messages (depending on the message type).

My problem is that I've got several consumers that are using `pollLastEntry()` in order to remove the highest priority message from the queue and then sleeping if the queue is empty, but the thing is that queue activity goes in bursts - it will go an hour without containing more than a few messages, and then in the next hour it will never empty.  As such I'd like to use a blocking method to remove messages from the queue so that I don't waste resources on repeatedly sleeping threads (I'd use exponential backoff to make them sleep longer when there's less activity, but this would make them unresponsive when the queue starts up again), but am unclear as to the best way to go about implementing this - I have plenty of experience with *using* blocking queues, but zero experience with implementing them.  My first thought was to implement exponential backoff in the sleeping consumers and then interrupt them when queue activity starts up again, but I first wanted to see if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at [Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html), specifically `wait`/`notify` may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a wrapper

```
class Wrapper implements Comparable<Wrapper> {
    long priority;
    Message message;

    Wrapper(long priority, Message message) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Wrapper w) {
        return Long.compare(priority, w.priority);
    }
}
```

and used PriorityBlockingQueue instead of ConcurrentSkipListMap

Comment: Nuts, I can't believe I missed that in the concurrent package